# Calculating the age of the universe by evaluating amounts of uranium isotopes

Tags: calculus

**The problem**
According to a cosmological theory, there were equal amounts of the uranium isotopes U-235 and U-238 at the big bang. The isotopes have the following half-lives;

- 4.51 billion years for U-238
- 0.71 billion years for U-235

Today, there is 137.7 times as many U-238 atoms as there are U-235 atoms.

Calculate the age of the universe according to this cosmological theory.

**My attempt** so far has been to look at the factor between the amounts as a function $f(t)$, with $f(0) = 1$ as there were equal amounts in the beginning, and $f(n) = 137.7$. I'm trying then to find an appropriate $n$ using the half-life information, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Given
$\require{mhchem}
\begin{cases}
f_{\ce{U238}}(t) = 2^{-t/4.51}\\
f_{\ce{U235}}(t) = 2^{-t/0.71}
\end{cases}$. What is the $t$ which make $f_{\ce{U238}}(t)/f_{\ce{U235}}(t) = 137.7$?

As a side note, this estimation of age of universe is faulty. The current belief are elements above $\ce{Fe}$ are mostly created through [Supernova nucleosynthesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supernova_nucleosynthesis). This estimation only provide a lower bound to the age of this universe.

Comment: Thanks. And yeah, I'm aware that this theory is flawed, but I didn't want to mention any of that in the problem statement since it was pretty obvious. I mean, as far as I know, first moments of the big bang are pretty irregular in terms of "time" as we know it, so I thought the problem was sketchy already there.